# Generic type resolution in tsx files

Tags: typescript, tsx

I'm trying to understand if there is a limitation to type inference with using tsx files in typescript.

If I create a stateless react component:

```
interface TestProps {
    foo: string;
}

export const TestComp: React.StatelessComponent<TestProps> = x => {
    return(<div>{foo}</div>);
};
```

and then in a second tsx file try the following:

```
import { TestComp } from './TestComp';

const getProperties = function<P>(node: React.ReactElement<P>) : P {
    return node.props
};

var props1 = getProperties(React.createElement(TestComp, { foo : 'bar' }));
var props2 = getProperties(<TestComp foo='bar' />);
```

props1 will have an inferred type of *TestProps*, props2 will have an inferred type of *any*.

I was under the impression that the two last lines were equivalent. Is there a reason that Typescript believes object in the second call to be a `React.ReactElement<any>`?

Comment: After further investigation it appears to work if I define TestComp as a normal function instead of an arrow function `export function TestComp(props: TestProps) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael's answer pointed me in the right direction because it got me digging into the .d.ts files for React, but the actual reason is more subtle.

This block of code

```
export const TestComp: React.StatelessComponent<TestProps> = x => {
    return(<div>{foo}</div>);
};
```

Using the interface defined as in the react .d.ts as:

```
interface StatelessComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: P & { children?: ReactNode }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null;
    ...
}
```

This shows that `x` will have an inferred type of `TestProps & { children?: ReactNode }`. This works fine and can be seen in the intellisense results from VS Code.

However, the return type of that function *isn't* `ReactElement<TestProps>` as I expected, it is `ReactElement<any>`.

By comparison createElement is defined as:

```
function createElement<P>(
    type: SFC<P>,
    props?: Attributes & P,
    ...children: ReactNode[]): SFCElement<P>;
```

where

```
type SFC<P = {}> = StatelessComponent<P>;
interface SFCElement<P> extends ReactElement<P> { }
```

Calling `React.createElement(TestComp, { foo : 'bar' })` allows the generic parameter of `TestProps` from `TestComp` to bubble all the way up into the final created element.

To summarise: By explicitly defining `TestComp` as a `StatelessComponent<TestProps>` I have also defined the returned element from the factory function as a `ReactElement<any>`. Removing this definition and writing the component as:

```
export function TestComp(x: TestProps) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
export const TestComp = (x: TestProps) => {
    ....
}
```

Gives Typescript *less* information and allows it to infer the correct type rather than forcing it to use the wrong one...

Answer (score 1):

Just some syntax mixups here. Your arrow function is not doing what you think it does:

```
export const TestComp: React.StatelessComponent<TestProps> = x => {
    return(<div>{foo}</div>);
};
```

has `x` typed as `any`. Furthermore, `x` isn't even used in the function. What you really want is:

```
export const TestComp: React.StatelessComponent<TestProps> = (x: TestProps) => {
    return(<div>{x.foo}</div>);
};
```

As an aside, a quick stylistic note about arrow functions: I usually only use arrow functions if I'd otherwise be forced to use `bind`. In this simple example, I would actually *prefer* to use a normal function since there's no funky business with `this` going on.

Comment: Yeah, the missing `x` in the function was a typo as I was trying to simplify my real code down to an example for the question. I've decided to move to normal functions for a number of reasons (primarily it improves the component names in enzyme/jest test snapshots), but coming from a C# background I was preferring the way that arrow functions handled `this` as it is closer to my mental model...